# Android get the values of dynamically created items

Tags: android

I am creating views like EditText,RadioButtons checkBoxes etc. dynamically as per the response from web service. Now, I need to get the values of all created views in single HashMap or any Map. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

you can use the `View.getId()` function for that

Comment: Also the user has to `view.setId()` for relevant view then he can use `view.getId()`